# Bootstrap popover not working despite being initialized (script tags issue?)

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add bootstrap popovers to buttons on my webapp but for some reason they don't show.

I'm initiating popovers in .js script in my Django template with:

`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`

I've tried variety of similar implementations, yet without any success.

Despite using code that works in fiddles I cannot recreate the effect within my app.
I'm assuming it's a matter of script tags, yet trying same tags as in some solutions didn't help much either.
Is there some conflict or am I short of some tags?

Here are my script tags:

```
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js">
    <link href="../static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!-- Fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Prosto+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Theme style  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/bootstrap/css/style.css">
    <!--star ratings-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'star-ratings/css/star-ratings.css' %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'star-ratings/js/dist/star-ratings.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: your bootstrap css and bootstrap js version are same or not ? bootstrap 3.3.7 have popover support ?

Comment: popper.js are not to be written in link tag

Comment: I've upgraded it. There's no difference in versions now and yet no popovers have appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrange your links & scripts like that and changed your CDN of bootstrap to latest version `4.3`

```
<!-- Fonts-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Prosto+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="../static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!-- jQuery UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<!--star ratings-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'star-ratings/css/star-ratings.css' %}">
<!-- Theme style  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/bootstrap/css/style.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'star-ratings/js/dist/star-ratings.min.js' %}"></script>
```

**POPOVER EXAMPLE**

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
});
```

```html
<!-- Fonts-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Prosto+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top
</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've changed my file as you instructed. It did not help. I've made sure to have same version of bootstrap CSS and JS files. I'm clueless now.

Comment: glad you like my answer